# PTIJ: What did Egyptian vampires drink during the Makkah of Dam?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What happened if an Egyptian vampire living during the Makkah of Dam siphoned on a neck for blood? Was he punished with water instead?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

The passuk says

הֶן עָם כְּלָבִיא יָקוּם וְכַאֲרִי יִתְנַשָּׂא לֹא יִשְׁכַּב עַד יֹאכַל טֶרֶף וְדַם חֲלָלִים יִשְׁתֶּה.

And we make a *gezerah shaveh* to the *passuk*

וְהַשְּׁתִיָּה כַדָּת אֵין אֹנֵס

So you see it is *mutar* for a vampire to drink dead men's blood.

Now the only reason a vampire gets *hanaah* from drinking blood is because *mayim genuvim yimtaku*, and blood for a vampire is the same as water for everyone else, as you say in your question.

So during the *makkah* of *dam* Egyptian vampires were punished by making their blood taste like *dam chalalim*.